# Fancybox-2 : Stops working when updating original element dynamically

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

So, here's the scenario: I'm trying to make a gallery of sorts where there is a 'main' image that has Fancybox enabled ( with a class of `.fancybox` ) and below this main image is a few thumbnails which, when clicked, update the `href` and `src` of the main `<a>` and `<img>` elements, respectively.

Now, when the page loads, if you click the main image, the Fancybox fires with no issue as expected. However, when I click one of the thumbnails below, the main image and link update with the thumbnails content -- if I click the main image now, it just goes to the specified URL; no Fancybox.

Even if I were to re-call the `$('.fancybox').fancybox();` after the swap has taken place; nothing still.

At any rate, here's the code and jsFiddle:

---

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/jRsjK/4481/

---

**HTML**

```
<!-- The "Main" Photo -->
<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>

<!-- The thumbnails that update the main photo -->
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="update" href="http://placekitten.com/600/300" title="This is the test title.">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" width="45" width="45" title="This is the test title." />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="update" href="http://placekitten.com/600/300" title="This is the test title.">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/149" width="45" width="45" title="This is the test title." />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="update" href="http://placekitten.com/600/300" title="This is the test title.">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" width="45" width="45" title="This is the test." />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

**JS**

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    live: true
});

$('.update').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var main      = $('.fancybox'),
        href      = $(this).prop('href'),
        title     = $(this).prop('title'),
        img_src   = $(this).find('img').prop('src'),
        img_title = $(this).find('img').prop('title');

    main
        .prop('title', title)
        .prop('href', href)
        .find('img')
        .prop('src', img_src)
        .prop('title', img_title);

    $(".fancybox").fancybox();

});
```

---

I'm probably too focused to pick up anything obvious so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason fancybox works the first time is because, the first link's URL targets an *image*, e.g. :

```
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg
```

... while the others to a *location*, e.g. :

```
http://placekitten.com/600/300
```

... without any *image* extension. In the second URL, fancybox doesn't know what `type` of content to handle and this is why the link opens in a new window/tab.

You have to force the `type` of content to *`image`* like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type : "image"
});
```

You don't actually need to `re-call the $('.fancybox').fancybox(); after the swap has taken place`

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsgfm/)**