# How to make Fancybox work in Pagelime CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, fancybox, fancybox-2

I´ve noticed that Fancybox cant handle Pagelime autogenerated href links...

Here it works > http://miaumiauestudio.com/artistas/colmegna/

But here, after some user uploads some content and publishes it href turns in something like "cms-assets/images/820798.ale-seeber---st--oil-on-canvas---116-x"
and prevents Fancybox from working right!

http://miaumiauestudio.com/artistas/seeber/

Is there any solution?

I´m calling fancybox from "rel" attribute to avoid other errors,
but dont know how to make this href link address!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox();

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support FAQs tab, No.5 for a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox-2 : Stops working when updating original element dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093849/fancybox-2-stops-working-when-updating-original-element-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you JFK but I managed to get it working, the problem was that when uploading an image thru Pagelime Image Browser, file name is modified adding an autogenerated numeric code... in some cases when your file name has lots of characters from the start, auto-renaming clears the file extension ".jpg" (Pagelime issue :S)

Comment: I solved this by renaming every image and uploading it again with shorter names and it worked!